# How to check if ManualResetEvent has been disposed, when trying to Set() it inside an EventHandler?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, design-patterns, dispose

I have the following design pattern:

```
    var myObjectWithEvents = new ObjectWithEvents();
    using (var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false)) {
        var onEvent = new EventHandler<EventArgs>((sender, e) => { mre.Set(); });   
        try {
            myObjectWithEvents.OnEvent += onEvent;
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                myObjectWithEvents.DoSomethingThatShouldRaiseAnEvent();
            });
            var timedOut = !mre.WaitOne(10000);
        }
        finally {
            myObjectWithEvents.OnEvent -= onEvent;
        }
    }
```

My issue is that if `OnEvent` is raised after the `WaitOne` times out and execution steps out of the using block, the local `onEvent` event handler will still be called and try to set the `ManualResetEvent mre` which will have already been disposed, even though `onEvent` should have been unregistered from `OnEvent`.

A simple workaround would be to check if `mre` has already been disposed, but unfortunately there is no such field, and I believe wrapping `mre.Set()` inside a try catch block to ignore the exception is not clean given that the exception could occur quite frequently.

What would you suggest as the best and simplest way to achieve the purpose of the above code pattern (i.e. waiting for an event to be raised) without running into this kind of issue?

**Edit:** Thanks to your answers, I created the following extension and replaced `mre.Set()` with `mre.TrySet()`:

```
    public static void TrySet(this ManualResetEvent mre) {
        if (!mre.SafeWaitHandle.IsClosed) mre.Set();
    }
```

Comment: Could you give more detail about your application requirements? You ask for "the best and simplest way to achieve the purpose of the above code pattern," but that leaves us guessing what your requirements are based off of your current code.

Comment: Does it cause any issues executing Set() on disposed MRE?

Comment: Yes mre.Set() on disposed mre will throw an exception...

Comment: However, please note that the "answer" code above is not fully correct since it manifests a race condition where 'mre.SafeWaitHandle.IsClosed' can become true after you've examined it, but before mre.Set() is reached. I consider the pointless exception-throwing behavior a design flaw in .NET because I see no correct way to work around this race condition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to check it by the mre.SafeWaitHandle.IsClosed property

Answer (score 13):

```
ManualResetEvent.SafeWaitHandle.IsClosed
```

Seems strange, but the only thing that the dispose does is to close the safeHandler, which is the only object that its the dispose intended to...

The Dispose of the SafeWaitHandle, changes this property from False to True.

Answer (score 1):

As a case try out using simple boolean switch which indicating whether setting manualResetEvent is actual:

```
bool isMreSync = true;
var myObjectWithEvents = new ObjectWithEvents();
using (var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false)) 
{
    var onEvent = new EventHandler<EventArgs>((sender, e) => 
                 { 
                     if (isMreSync)
                     {
                         mre.Set(); 
                     }
                 });

  // try ... finally block  
 }

isMreSync = false;
```

If event might be executed asynchronously - synchronize access to boolean switch.

Comment: I think this solution is not quite safe, it can happen that `isMreSync` is set to false (and even disposed) right after the check and before calling `Set`, since there is no additional locking.